# How to receive data from nested collection in Firebase using StreamBuilder and ListView?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to receive all tracks from next path:

"main_page_items" Collection -> album_id Document -> "tracks" Collection -> track_id Document

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    import 'package:app/album.dart';
    
    class SongList extends StatelessWidget {
      final callback;
      final album;
    
      SongList(this.callback, this.album);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream : FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("tracks")
                    .where("main_page_items", isEqualTo: album).snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              final List<DocumentSnapshot> tracks = snapshot.data!.docs ;
              //print(tracks);
              print(tracks.length);
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: tracks.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 16, 12),
                    child: SongItem(
                        tracks[index]['title'],
                        tracks[index]['artist'],
                        tracks[index]['image'],
                        tracks[index]['url'],
                        callback),
                  );
                },
              );
              
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class SongItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final title;
  final artist;
  final image;
  final url;
  final callback;
  SongItem(this.title, this.artist, this.image, this.url, this.callback);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            callback(title, artist, image, url);
          },
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 60.0,
                    width: 60.0,
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                      child: Image.network(
                        image,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 16.0),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                  Text(
                    artist,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5), fontSize: 14.0),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

But if i've got a "0" value of length of snapshot, and if i try to print the docs (tracks variable), i've got an empty [], but i have one element in the Firestore DB.
What is the problem and how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: What is the type of `album`?

Answer (score 1):

id doesn't seem that the database links that you said it wat actually you used in the code :

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection("tracks")
.where("main_page_items", isEqualTo: album).snapshots(),
```

by using this, you're likely refer to tracks as a the most parent collection in your database, but from what you provided, that tracks is a sub-collection and should be accessed like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection("main_page_items")
.document("album_id")
.collection("tracks")
.snapshots(),
```